# is it possible to deduce user data into inheritance using the overload operator?

Tags: c++

for example, I have a base class Unit and Unit has heirs, for example **Soldier, Vampire**. They have their own lives and damage. Is it possible to display data Vampire, Soldier using a separate class for example **StateOfUnits** where there is an overload of the output operator.

something like :

**base class :**

```
class Unit {
private:
    int hpLimit;
    int dmg;
    int hp;
    std::string name;
public:
    Unit(int hpLimit = 100, int dmg = 10, const std::string& name = "noname");
    ~Unit();

    int getDamage() const;
    int getHP() const;
    int getHpLimit() const;
    const std::string& getName() const;
};
```

**class that displays statistics:**

```
class StateOfUnits {
    ///may be some code...
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Unit& unit) {
        out << "HP of " << unit.getName() << " is : " << unit.getHP() << "/" << unit.getHpLimit() << std::endl;
        out << "Damage of " << unit.getName() << " is : " << unit.getDamage() << std::endl;
        return out;
}
```

**main:**

```
int main() {
                hp  dmg  name
Vampire vampire(100,25,"Vampire");
Soldier soldier(120, 20, "Soldier");

cout << soldier << endl;
cout << vampire << endl;

return 0;

}
```

**I hope I explained it clearly.**

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but i don't think you did explain it clearly. Where would the StateOfUnits class come in?

Comment: @Wutz this is a separate class for displaying Unit data, using the output operator

Comment: Can you add it to your example? I don't understand what your plan is.

Comment: please show a [mre] of what you're trying to achieve and what isn't working

Comment: What you just edited in should work pretty much unchanged, if you're just after the operator. You don't need the additional class, you can simply define the operator in any header file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if `StateOfUnit` is a base class:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct StateOfUnit
{
    int hp;
    int dmg;
    string  name;

    StateOfUnit(int hp, int dmg, string name)
        : hp(hp), dmg(dmg), name(name)
        {}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const StateOfUnit& s)
     { 
         return os << s.hp << '\t' << s.dmg << '\t' << s.name;
     }
};

struct Soldier : StateOfUnit
{
    using StateOfUnit::StateOfUnit;
};

struct Vampire : StateOfUnit
{
    using StateOfUnit::StateOfUnit;
};

int main() {
    Vampire vampire(100,25,"Vampire");
    Soldier soldier(120, 20, "Soldier");

    cout << soldier << endl;
    cout << vampire << endl;

    return 0;
}
```